# What does "this" keyword means in default ArrayList constructor?

Tags: java, arraylist

Take a look at default ArrayList constructor:

```
public ArrayList() {
       this(10);
}
```

`this(10);` looks like some method invocation, but there is no such method in ArrayList. This constr has following description- "Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten." Obviously 10 in  `this(10);` determine capacity of AL.
So what is this - some keyword or what?

Comment: `this` is a keyword, and it means you are calling one constructor from another. Note: a constructor is a special kind of method.

Comment: this keyword refers to the object of the same class itself and (10) refers to parameterized constructor in the same class itself with number type of argument.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a keyword in java which refers to it self as object. 
`this(10)` in the empty constructor is like `new ArrayList(10)` its a coding style called *cascading constructors*.
You also have to use this when for example you have a setter method which sets an value variable and the parameter has the same name as the object variable so you have to use `this` to referd to the object variable and not to the parameter.
You find more informations here:
[Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's calling another constructor which must take an integer argument.

`this` is a keyword used to refer to "this" instance; the one calling `this(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

it refers to another constructor of ArrayList

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity);
```

which creates ArrayList with allocated some space given in parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a keyword in Java.

Explained here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html