# I'm trying to understand dynamic arrays, I'm stuck on line 7, this(16); Is reference to the size of the array?

Tags: java, dynamic-arrays

I'm starting at Free Code Camps but I had never seen line 7-- this(16); I would appreciate if you told me what it does and where I can read more about it.

```
public class DynamicArray<T> implements Iterable<T> {

  private T[] arr;// define atributo array del tipo t(vector)
  private int len = 0; // length user thinks array is
  private int capacity = 0; // Actual array size

  public DynamicArray() {
      this(16);   // <-- This line
  }

  public DynamicArray(int capacity) {
    if (capacity < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: " + capacity);
    this.capacity = capacity;
    arr = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
  }
```

Comment: [Read this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35927764/what-does-this-keyword-means-in-default-arraylist-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

"this" means the object itself, which is an instance of class DynamicArray. You can get an instance of DynamicArray by calling

```
DynamicArray myArray = new DynamicArray();
```

Then `myArray` is the object that `this` points to. While `this(16)` is calling `public DynamicArray(int capacity)` on the object `myArray`. So，16 is the argument that will be passed to the parameter `capacity`.